# Why $\eta$ must not be equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I was trying to understand the derivation of Euler-Lagrange Equations, but there are some things that really don't make sense to me.

For example, in [this video](https://youtu.be/SQLxrr9N8zM?t=1130) at minute 18:50, it is said that we don't want it to have zero variation.
$$
\hat{y}(x) = y(x) + \varepsilon \eta(x)\\
\frac{\delta S}{\delta F} = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}{\eta(x) \left \{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right) \right \} \;dt} = 0\\
\eta \neq 0 \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right) = 0
$$

But why? You are seeking for THE function that minimizes something; if you allow it to have some variation, $\eta(x)$, then it is not your function (because you arrive to the function you are seeking for, when the variation is $0$), no? I would appreciate some help and some in-depth exaplanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a miscommunication.  What we want is for the expression
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta F}[y;\eta]&=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\eta(x)\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(x,y(x),y'(x))}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\bigg|_{(x,y(x),y'(x))}\right)\right]\,dx
\end{align}
to be zero **for all** sufficiently smooth $\eta$ which vanish at the endpoints. This is just the condition that a function $y$ is a stationary point for the 'action' functional $S$. Now If this integral is $0$ for all such $\eta$, then the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations tells us the thing in square brackets must be zero on the entire interval $[x_0,x_1]$. Thus, you obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations.

---

Also, 'minimization' is just a colloquial term. This is really just a condition for stationarity.